# Cómo agregar a un árbol correctamente?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

He intentado trabajar con esta función, pero lo unico que hace es llenar la raiz. Intento hacer un árbol binario y, cuando ingreso los valores, lo único que hace es la raíz, no agrega hijos ni a la izquierda ni a la derecha

Lo que pasa es que por ejemplo ingreso 2, luego 3, luego 1, el padre tendría que ser 2, hijo izquierdo 1, hijo derecho 3, pero lo único que esto hace es meterse únicamente el padre. Si pongo 2 el padre es 2, si pongo 3 el padre es 3, no hace el árbol solamnte la raiz es agregada

Aqui esta mi metodo mas abajao la clase donde se encuentra

```
    public void addNodo(Nodo nodo, Nodo raiz) {
    Principal p = new Principal();

    if (raiz==null) {

        this.setRaiz(nodo);
        System.out.println("Agrego raiz");
    } else if (nodo.getValor() <= raiz.getValor()) {
        if (raiz.getHojaIzquierda() == null) {
            raiz.setHojaIzquierda(nodo);
        } else {
            addNodo(nodo, raiz.getHojaIzquierda());
        }
        System.out.println("Agrego izquierda");

   } else{
        if (raiz.getHojaDerecha() == null) {
             raiz.setHojaDerecha(nodo);
        } else {
             addNodo(nodo, raiz.getHojaDerecha());
        }
        System.out.println("Agrego derecha");
   }
}
```

tengo mi clase nodo

```
    public class Nodo {
    /* Declaraciones de variables */
    private int valor;

    private Nodo padre;
    private Nodo hojaIzquierda;
    private Nodo hojaDerecha;

    /* Constructor */
    public Nodo(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    /* Setters y Getters */
    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public Nodo getPadre() {
        return padre;
    }

    public void setPadre(Nodo padre) {
        this.padre = padre;
    }

    public Nodo getHojaIzquierda() {
        return hojaIzquierda;
    }

    public void setHojaIzquierda(Nodo hojaIzquierda) {
        this.hojaIzquierda = hojaIzquierda;
    }

    public Nodo getHojaDerecha() {
        return hojaDerecha;
    }

    public void setHojaDerecha(Nodo hojaDerecha) {
        this.hojaDerecha = hojaDerecha;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ""+valor;
    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase arbol

```
public class Arbol {

/* Atributos */
public Arbol() {
}

private Nodo raiz;

/* Contructories */
public Arbol(int valor) {
    this.raiz = new Nodo(valor);
}

public Arbol(Nodo raiz) {
    this.raiz = raiz;
}

/* Setters y Getters */
public Nodo getRaiz() {
    return raiz;
}

public void setRaiz(Nodo raiz) {
    this.raiz = raiz;
}

// ---> Aquí esta mi metodo con problemas <---
public void addNodo(Nodo nodo, Nodo raiz) {
    Principal p = new Principal();

    if (raiz==null) {
        this.setRaiz(nodo);
        System.out.println("Agrego raiz");
    } else if (nodo.getValor() <= raiz.getValor()) {

        if (raiz.getHojaIzquierda() == null) {
            raiz.setHojaIzquierda(nodo);
        } else {
            addNodo(nodo, raiz.getHojaIzquierda());
        }
        System.out.println("Agrego izquierda");

    } else{
        if (raiz.getHojaDerecha() == null) {
            raiz.setHojaDerecha(nodo);
        } else {
            addNodo(nodo, raiz.getHojaDerecha());
        }
        System.out.println("Agreago derecha");
    }
}

public void addNodo(Nodo nodo) {
    this.addNodo(nodo, this.raiz);
}
```

Comment: Sería útil tener un test o un ejemplo de cómo usas este método

Comment: Con un poquito de mejor redacción se ven más claros los datos de prueba que te han pedido y se entiende mejor el problema. Te ayudo con una edición de tu pregunta para que se vea más clara.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que aconsejo es que replantees los métodos de tu árbol `addNodo(Nodo nodo, Nodo raiz)` y `public void addNodo(Nodo nodo)`.

Yo los trabajo de la siguiente manera:

```
    public void addNodo(Nodo nodo) {
        //Primero esta validación ya que existe la posibilidad de que la 
        //raiz este siempre con un valor asignado
        if (raiz != null) {
            addNodo(nodo, raiz);
        }else {
            raiz = nodo;
        }
    }

    private void addNodo(Nodo nodo, Nodo padre) {
        if (nodo.getValor() > padre.getValor()) {
            if (padre.getHojaDerecha() != null) {
                //Se aplica recursividad para ir recorriendo el árbol por la 
                //rama derecha
                addNodo(nodo, padre.getHojaDerecha());
            }else {
                //Se asigna el nodo en la posición vacia encontrada a la 
                //derecha
                padre.setHojaDerecha(nodo);
            }
        }else {
            if (padre.getHojaIzquierda() != null) {
                //Se aplica recursividad para ir recorriendo el árbol por la 
                //rama izquierda
                addNodo(nodo, padre.getHojaIzquierda());
            }else {
                //Se asigna el nodo en la posición vacia encontrada a la 
                //izquierda
                padre.setHojaIzquierda(nodo);
            }
        }
    }
```

En este link encontraras mayor información sobre los arboles binarios, http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html y en el siguiente link información con respecto a la recursividad https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y bienvenido.. solo como una formalidad y para que sepas como funcionamos, podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Con estos métodos puedes solucionar tu problema al agregar.

```
public void add(Node node) {
    if (root != null) {
        add(root, node);
    }else {
        root = node;
    }
}

private void add(Node base, Node node) {
    if (node.getInformation() < base.getInformation()) {
        if (base.getLeft() != null) {
            add(base.getLeft(), node);
        }else {
            base.setLeft(node);
        }
    }else {
        if (base.getRight() != null) {
            add(base.getRight(), node);
        }else {
            base.setRight(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve el problema? Procura siempre incluir una breve explicación de cómo usar ésto y en qué cambia el problema.